# Can't find "iplink" program on rooted phone

Tags: terminal, busybox, mac-address

I'm using LG Optimus Black P970 with ICS 4.0.4. After rooting my phone, when I'm writing in the terminal the command `busybox iplink show eth0`, it shows `iplink applet not found`. What should I do? Also how do I find `/data/misc/wifi`?

Answer (score 2):

It's "`ip link show`", not "`iplink show`".  You're missing a space.

As for "how to find `/data/misc/wifi`", it's unclear what you mean by "find" it; that's the path that says where it is.  In the root directory (`/`) there's a directory called `data`, and in that there's another directory called `misc`, and in that there's a directory called `wifi`.

It sounds like you're following a tutorial and typing commands without having any understanding of what they mean.  It'd be a good idea to familiarize yourself with the basics of how a Linux system works before you go mucking about with root on your phone.

Comment: After typing in the terminal "busybox ip link show eth0", it is showing that "ip: can't find device etho". What to do next. It's true that I'm not a technical person, but I want to learn the rooting process.